# Text search in Eclipse CDT won't show results from include paths

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to find certain text(bug number -- it resides in comments) in my Eclipse CDT project. The results will not show anything from the header files in include paths although some header files contain that text.

However, C/C++ search does find all the symbols from the header files in include paths too. Unfortunately, I can't do simple text search from C/C++ search tab. I understand that it's intended for searching C/C++ terms.

It appears that Eclipse CDT won't even index normal text in header files residing in include paths. Is this true? How can I make Eclipse to index normal text in include paths?

Comment: Any news on this ?